# Validação de formulário com dois botões

Tags: javascript, formulário, validação

estou dificuldade em validar um formulário, mas da forma que estou tentando não sei se é possível, alguém pode me dar uma força?

Tenho um formulário com dois botões `submit`.
E na tag `form` estou colocando o `onsubmit = "checa_formulario()"`
Porém, um dos botões deve realizar o submit sem entrar nesta funcão do `onsubmit`, mas o outro botão deve executar essa função.

Tentei chamar essa função no `onclick` do botão que quero que execute a função, mas aí ele executava a função, mas independente do resultado, ele realizava o submit.

Devo utilizar javascript puro.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Desde já agradeço!

EDIT

Tenho dois botões:

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="1">
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="2">
```

O botão com `value = 1`, quando clicado, deve entrar na função `checa_formulario()`.

Já o botão com `value = 2`, quando clicado, não deve executar a função `checa_formulario()`, mas deve realizar o submit.

Estou chamando a função dentro do `onsubmit` na tag form, visto que, os dois botões devem realizar submit, a diferença entre um e outro, é que, um faz validação e o outro não.

```
<form method="POST" action="arquivo.php" onsubmit="return checa_formulario()">
```

E essa é a função:

```
if (document.getElementById('descri_icon').value.length < 10) {
    alert("Erro");
    return (false);
}
```

Este id, `descri_icon` é de uma `textarea`, e a única verificação é ver se nela, tem o minimo de caracteres pedido, mas isso, se o botão com `value = 1` for clicado.

Comment: Você poderia explicar melhor sua pergunta?

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta com código para explicar melhor

Comment: Editei a pergunta

Comment: tenho uma pergunta, quando se apertar um necessariamente o outro não tem que ser ativado nunca? ou pode acontecer dos dois?

Comment: Até podem ser ativado os dois, mas a função só deve ser chamada com o click no botão com value = 1

Comment: É um formulário bem extenso, então o botão com value = 1 conclui o formulario, e o botão com value = 2 salva tudo que ja foi preenchido no formulario mas não o conclui... então o botão com value = 2 não precisa de validação

Comment: Mas o botão com value = 2 ainda sim precisa do submit porque preciso das informações do post para salvar em um banco de dados

Comment: Vc pode desabilitar um botão quando o outro for clicado.. assim $('button').prop('disabled', !preenchidos);

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6819/como-habilitar-um-bot%C3%A3o-apenas-quando-todos-os-inputs-estiverem-preenchidos

Comment: Sabe me dizer como eu faria isso com javascript? Pois não estou podendo usar jquery :/

Comment: Aqui tem uma solução https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22439/como-habilitar-e-desabilitar-bot%C3%A3o-a-partir-do-onclick-ou-onchange-do-select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obrigado a todos pela ajuda!

Solucionei da seguinte forma:

```
<!-- Botões -->
<button type="button" name="btnComValidacao" value="1" 
onclick="checa_formulario()">
<button type="submit" name="btnSemValidacao" value="2">
```

E a função `checa_formulario()`

```
function checa_formulario(){
                if (document.getElementById('descri_icon').value.length < 10){
                  alert("erro");
                  return (false);
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('form').submit();
                }
        }
```

E tirei o onsubmit da tag `<form>`.

Assim, quando clicado no botao com `value = 2`, que ja é do tipo `submit`, ele da o `submit`.
E quando clicado no botao com `value = 1`, que é do tipo `button`, ele primeiro entra na função e verifica a `textarea`, se o `if` der falso, ele realiza o `submit`

Answer (score 1):

**1. Trabalhando com inputs**

No script verifique o nome do botão clicado, e nos botões `onclick="checa_formulario(this.name,this.form)"`

```js
function checa_formulario(NomeBotao,form){
if(NomeBotao == "bt1"){
    if (document.getElementById('descri_icon').value.length < 10) { 
        alert("Erro");
        return false;
    }
}
form.submit();
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="https://pt.stackoverflow.com/">
 <textarea id="descri_icon" name="descri_icon"></textarea>
 <input type="button" name="bt1" value="1" onclick="checa_formulario(this.name,this.form)">
 <input type="button" name="bt2" value="2" onclick="checa_formulario(this.name,this.form)">
</form>
```

**2. Trabalhando com `<button>`**

```js
function checa_formulario()
{
   if (document.getElementById('descri_icon').value.length < 10) { 
   alert("Erro");
   return false;
   }    
document.getElementById('myform').submit();
}

var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", checa_formulario);
```

```html
<form id="myform" method="POST" action="https://pt.stackoverflow.com/" >
   <textarea id="descri_icon" name="descri_icon"></textarea>
   <button type="button" id="btn" value="1">1</button>
   <button type="submit" id="btn2" value="2">2</button>
</form>
```

Pode-se substituir essas duas linhas

`var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", checa_formulario);`

do código acima pelo evento

`onclick="checa_formulario()"`

diretamente no botão

```js
function checa_formulario()
{
   if (document.getElementById('descri_icon').value.length < 10) { 
   alert("Erro");
   return false;
   }    
document.getElementById('myform').submit();
}
```

```html
<form id="myform" method="POST" action="https://pt.stackoverflow.com/" >
   <textarea id="descri_icon" name="descri_icon"></textarea>
   <button type="button" id="btn" value="1" onclick="checa_formulario()">1</button>
   <button type="submit" id="btn2" value="2">2</button>
</form>
```

### Sobre o atributo type dos buttons

1. submit: O botão envia os dados do formulário para o servidor.
2. button: O botão não possui comportamento padrão. Ele pode ter scripts do lado do cliente associado com os eventos do elemento, no qual são acionados quando o evento ocorrer.

[`<button>` - Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)