# Habilitar button quando os campos forem preenchidos

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, formulário

sei que já existem alguns tópicos com o mesmo tema, mas meu caso é um pouco mais específico. Tenho um formulário com alguns campos ocultos que só aparecem de acordo com o `change` de alguns `selects`.

Eu queria que meu botão de submit só ficasse habilitado quando todos os meus campos estivessem preenchidos, então achei a solução na resposta do @Sergio nesse tópico:

[Como habilitar um botão apenas quando todos os inputs estiverem preenchidos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6819/como-habilitar-um-bot%C3%A3o-apenas-quando-todos-os-inputs-estiverem-preenchidos)

Aí que começa o problema. O código funciona, porém o botão não ativa até que todos os campos **ocultos** também sejam preenchidos. E muitas vezes as escolhas do usuário farão com que esses campos não apareçam.

Tem alguma forma de fazer esse código "ignorar" esses campos ocultos? Ou só verificar se eles estão preenchidos quando eles estiverem visíveis?

Obrigado, e segue o código que estou usando:

```js
var inputs = $('input').on('keyup', verificarInputs);
function verificarInputs() {
    const preenchidos = inputs.get().every(({value}) => value)
    $('button').prop('disabled', !preenchidos);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Você pode usar um filter para pegar apenas os inputs que estão visíveis

```
inputs.filter((i, el) => $(el).is(':visible'))
```